# Frequency response of DC amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, dc, bode-plot, frequency-response

it is well known that the characteristics of a DC amplifier is realised by a bode plot which has gain and frequency on the y- and x- axis respectively. But frequency of DC is zero. How is it possible to plot a frequency based graph for DC op-amp ??
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: So indeed, theoretically **no conclusion** about the gain at DC can be  made about an amplifier by just looking at the Bode plot ! In practice, the behavior at DC is often (not always !) the same as the behavior at a very low frequency. So most time you can just use the low frequency value as the value for DC. This is true as long as the gain is flat at a low (enough) frequency. Exceptions are integrators and differentiators where the gain is not flat over frequency.

Comment: To the OP: Even though this is true, it is kind of similar to saying "there is no such thing as DC, because the current had to start some time, and it will stop someday, too, so it is not really DC."

Comment: Why not just calculate the gain at DC and use the Bode plot for everything else? In general, if it's a manufacturer's data sheet, the low- and high-frequency asymptotes can be assumed to continue unchanged to zero and infinity

Answer (score 1):

Some amplifiers are incapable of amplifying low-to-zero frequencies.  Those are called 'AC amplifiers'.   Amplifiers which are capable of amplification at
low-to-zero frequency are 'DC amplifiers'.   There is, technically,
no use for absolute DC amplification (it would take a day of testing to
find out that an amplifier 'only' goes down to 0.000 002 Hz),
so the terms are applied loosely.

When frequency response is plotted, measured points are at positive
frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that bode-plots for operational amplifiers (and amplifiers in general) are for *small signal* inputs. What this means is that we presume some steady state in DC (the biasing conditions) and then look at how the output changes for small changes at the input. DC makes no sense here (in fact, there is a difference between DC and a frequency of 0 Hz from a signal theory perspective but that is another story).

Also realize that a bode-plot is on a log-log graph. This means that 0 Hz is never on this graph. Think about it this way: if on a log-log plot you go from 10 Hz to 100 Hz by moving 1cm on the x-axis to the right, then you go from 10 Hz to 1 Hz by going 1cm to the left of the 10 Hz mark. Another 1cm to the left brings you to 0.1 Hz. Another 1cm gets you to 0.01 Hz. You can continue this till infinity, but you still will not have 0 Hz. Hence, *it is imposible to show 0 Hz on a Bode-plot*.

So how do we come up with this DC gain figure? We look at the poles and the zeros in an amplifier. As we go left of the first pole frequency, assuming there are no zeros to the left of this pole (which is in practice always the case), we know that the gain will be the same at any frequency between 0 and this frequency. This is the same as ignoring all frequency-dependent effects and looking at the idealized version of the amplifier. Since there are no more frequency-dependent effects at this point, nothing in the circuit cares about the frequency anymore - it's gain will be the same no matter what. Hence, for infinitly small frequencies, or DC in practice, the opamp will produce this voltage gain.